# Fourier coefficients of $\chi_E$ assuming $m(E)=1.$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$ having measure $1$. Prove that there is an integer $n\neq0$ such that $\int_Ee^{inx}dx\neq0$.

This is an exercise problem. A hint is given: periodize with period $2\pi$. However, I still do not have an idea how to prove it. Any help will be appreciated.